# Conversion from string "00-25-2011" to type 'Date' is not valid

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Why does the following code, throw an exception: "Conversion from string "00-25-2011" to type 'Date' is not valid."?

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        Dim Test As Date
        Test = "2012-01-25"
        MsgBox(Test)
        Test = Format(DateAdd("d", -31, Test), "mm-dd-yyyy")
        MsgBox(Test)
    End Sub
```

The same code runs successfully in a VB6 app.  I do not understand why the month part is: 00.

Comment: What does MsgBox method do in an asp.net application ? Is that your custom method ?

Comment: @Shyju, msgbox is a standard .NET Message Box.

Comment: In Web ? i mean ASP.NET ? You tagged ASP.NET !

Comment: MsgBox is a Winforms construct, it does not apply in ASP.NET.

Comment: @Dai,You can use Message boxes in ASP.NET for debugging.

Comment: I've just had a look at the source code to VB.NET's `MsgBox` function - using it for debugging seems like abusing it because the implementation is filled with error handlers. For debugging you should use IDE Debugging step-through and Watch.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use "MM" for months, not "mm" which denotes minutes.

Also, I recommend using DateTime.ParseExact as it gives you more control.

Comment: vbscript and vb6 "m" was month - vb.net it is "MM" , you got to this faster then me

Comment: Thanks +1.  Do you know why it is not a capital letter in VB6?

Comment: @Scott Selby, I think a VB6 app requires mm.

Answer (score 0):

The Format function you are applying returns a String, yet you are trying to assign it back to a Date.

Comment: The error was about the conversion of a string to date failing, not about a type mismatch in the assignment. Read the question title. :-)

Comment: Just trying to point out that the Format function is not needed.  When I first threw his code into the IDE and took out the Format, it worked perfectly.